# IAS Zone device enroll steps

Tags: zigbee

I'm making a source code, so that I can get an alarm information from the IAS sensor device.

I'm using the smartthings motion sensor and Xbee device to make a communication between the sensor and my computer.

I'm wondering the step to handle the IAS Zone device
well, let me show you how i understand this.

1. there are 2 types of devices, the CIE(coordinator), and the IAS Zone device(like motion, fire etc)
2. the CIE sends a 'enroll' message to the IAS Zone device
3. confirm success on the response message from the IAS Zone device
4. the CIE sends again a 'response' message to the IAS Zone device with ZoneID
5. after that, the CIE can get the alarm data from the IAS Zone device

I think step 4 is not correct.
Could anyone let me know the detail about it?
how to enroll and what is the 'response' message for the IAS Zone device, and what is the Zone Id and how to handle the ZoneID?

I'm focusing on the concept, not how to use method like 'EnrollRequestResp()'

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I hope it helps someone in the future.

> 1. there are 2 types of devices, the CIE(coordinator), and the IAS Zone device(like motion, fire etc)

Yes.

> 2. the CIE sends a 'enroll' message to the IAS Zone device

No.

2. CIE must write (using Write Request) to cluster `0x0500`, attribute `0x0010`, data type `IEEE address`, value CIE's 64-bit address (be careful, format is little endian).
3. CIE receives Write Response, indicating (hopefully) success.

NOTE: everything below happens only when the address has *changed* (!!!). To trigger the change again, change the address to `0x0000000000000000` (which is incidentally also the way to un-enroll the IAS Zone Device) and then back to CIE's.

4. CIE receives Zone Enroll Request
5. CIE sends Zone Enroll Response

You can then confirm that end device in enrolled by issuing Read Request on cluster `0x0500`, attribute `0x0000` (ZoneState).